# Check if a cells is numeric with blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel table:

[image]

I need to traverse column K performing calculations only in the rows where column K is a number.

As I have blank cells, `IsNumeric` functions does not work properly.

I tried the following code, but the `IsEmpty` function returns `False` for filled cells:

```
Sub mysub()

    For i = 24 to lastRow
    
        If Len(Cells(i, 11)) = 0 And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 11)) = False Then
    
            'rest of the code
    
        End if
    
    Next i

End sub
```

How can I do to solve it?

Comment: I'd advise you to replace the check `IF (A AND B=false)` by `IF (A AND NOT(B))`.

Comment: Did you try `isNumeric`?

Comment: @Dominique I tried but the result is still the same....

Comment: @Ike as I wrote in the question, I tried it, but isNumeric functions is true for blank cells.

Comment: Shouldn't you look for Len greater than zero and IsNumeric true?

Comment: Like `If Len(Cells(i, 11)) > 0 And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 11)) = True Then` or simply `If Len(Cells(i, 11)) > 0 And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 11)) Then`.

Comment: You're welcome. Extra tip: if possible try to avoid double negatives or any convoluted use of false/negative/empty and similar. They tend mess with our mind and makes it harder to read/debug a code. `IsEmpty(Cells(i, 11)) = False` is not the most readable phrase. `Not(IsEmpty(Cells(i, 11)))` might be better, but still kind of demanding. It might be better to use `IsEmpty(Cells(i, 11))` and just swap the "if true" part with the "else" part whether possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253902/discussion-between-evil-blue-monkey-and-irene-ortiz-de-guzman).

Answer (score 0):

Change 'Planilha1' to your sheet, try like same this:

```
Sub teste()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim x As Long

Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
LastRow = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To LastRow
        If Sh.Range("K" & x).MergeCells = False Then
            If IsNumeric(Sh.Range("K" & x).Value) Then
                Debug.Print Sh.Range("K" & x).Value
            End If
        End If
        
    Next x
End Sub
```